# how to issue sudo command using python

Tags: python, command, sudo

I need to issue "sudo service nginx status" to check for service status. I have the following:

```
import commands
service output = commands.getoutput("sudo service nginx status")
```

but I am getting "no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Does someone understand this?

Answer (score 1):

using `commands.getoutput` makes impossible to provide the user input that is required by sudo command.
The name is self explainable, you are interested only in the command output. `stdin` is closed.

There are several solutions for this:

1. Turn off the password verification for the sudo user that is launching this python script. (read about /etc/sudoers)
2. pipe your password: (unsafe/bad solution but easy)
   "echo YOURPASS | sudo ..."
3. check out `subprocess.popen` allowing you to provide input either from console or from file
   https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor